# How to handle FileSystemAlreadyExistsException?

Tags: java, java.nio.file

How should you handle a `FileSystemAlreadyExistsException` when calling [FileSystems.newFileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#newFileSystem(java.net.URI,java.util.Map))?

One way would be to use the already created FileSystem (`getFileSystem​`), but then you could run into problems when the original creator closes it while you are still using it.

In case there is no generic answer to this question, then what about `ZipFileSystem`s? Let's say I want to create one for a zip file and I do not know and cannot control whether a FileSystem already exists for this specific zip file.

Is there a reliable way to handle a `FileSystemAlreadyExistsException`?

Comment: You mean that within the same JVM you have no control over who is using which Zip file?

Comment: Yes, even though it is unlikely, but I want to protect against the case where for example a third-party library I am using might create a file system for the same resource.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being late here, but I just ran into this myself. There are several versions of the FileSystems.newFileSystem() call, some versions throw FileSystemAlreadyExistsException, some do not. I found that using the version that accepts a Path object did not throw the exception and allowed me to work around the issue I was having.

Comment: I don't think this completely answers this question, but it is useful nonetheless! There is one potential issue though: These methods seem to always create new file system instances. This defeats any concurrency guarantees made by `FileSystem`; modifications made to the file system might get lost, at least for `ZipFileSystem`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a try/catch block around the code that is causing the exception.

Comment: Hi, Zachary - the answer you gave links to a lengthy text, and the relation to the question is not immediately obvious. The requester might TLDR, because they think you just want the text to be read. If you have understood that linked text, why no give a short excerpt, at least additionally to the link?